# Prove $f(x) - [f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)]$ has a double root at $x-a$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, solution-verification, roots

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a polynomial of degree $\geq 2$.  Fix arbitrary $a \in \mathbb R$, and let $$c(x) = f(x) - [f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)].$$  Prove there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $c(x) = p(x)(x-a)^2$ with $c(x)$ having a Double root at $a$.  (Source: Based on Spivak.)

My proof is below.
I request verification and suggestions on the proof and its exposition.  *Note: Other proofs exists.  This question is to verify or critique **this** proof.*

---

By the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, since $a$ is a root of the polynomial $f(x) - f(a)$, there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $$f(x) - f(a) = p(x)(x-a).$$
Let $q(x) = p(x) - f'(a)$.  Since $c(x) = q(x)(x-a)$, it suffices to show $q(a) = 0$.

For $x \neq a$, $q(x) = \frac {c(x)}{x-a}$, and since $q$ is continuous, $$\begin{align*}
q(a) &= \lim_{x \to a} \frac {c(x)}{x-a} \\
&= \lim_{x \to a} \frac {f(x) - f(a) -f'(a)(x-a)}{x-a} \\
&= f'(a) - f'(a) \\
= 0.
\end{align*}$$
completing the proof.

Comment: "*a polynomial of degree $\geq 2$*" $\;-\;$ Your proof doesn't seem to be using this condition, which is, however, necessary.

Comment: The proof is correct but **the fundamental theorem of algebra** states that every non-constant single-variable polynomial with complex coefficients has at least one complex root, but actually you need **the remainder theorem** which states that when a polynomial $f(x)$ is divided by a linear polynomial $(x - a)$, then the remainder is equal to $f(a)$, indeed, by using the remainder theorem, you get that$$f(x)=q(x)(x-a)+f(a)$$where  $\,q(x)\,$ is the quotient of the division of $\,f(x)\,$ by $\,(x-a)\,.$

Comment: @dxiv $f(x) - f(a)$ is only a polynomial if degree $f$ is $\geq 1$.  I'm actually not sure where I use that degree $f \geq 2$ - can you help me?

Comment: @Angelo Can't I use FTA to conclude "If $g(x) := f(x) - f(a)$ has a root at $x-a$, then $g(x) = p(x)(x-a)$"?  That is, FTA states not only that the root exists, but that if $\{r_n\}$ are the roots of the polynomial $P$, then $P$ is the product of $(x -r_n)$ for all $n$?  With that, I don't need the remainder theorem at all, no?

Comment: @dxiv, the hypothesis “degree $\geqslant2$” is not necessary, in fact if the degree of the polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ is less than $2$, it results $\,c(x)=0\,$ and in that case there exists the polynomial $\,p(x)=0\,$ such that $\,c(x)=p(x)(x-a)^2\,.$

Comment: When you have "Let q(x)=p(x)+" , I think , that should be "Let q(x)=p(x)-" to match the title.

Comment: That may be technically true , @Angelo , though it will not give the Double root in the title.

Comment: @SRobertJames, actually you are not using the fundamental theorem of algebra but the remainder theorem which states that when a polynomial $f(x)$ is divided by a linear polynomial $(x-a)$, then the remainder is equal to  $f(a)$.

Comment: @Prem, in this case, the OP should write: Prove there exists a polynomial $p$ of degree $\geqslant0$ (which implies $p\not\equiv0$) such that $c(x)=p(x)(x-a)^2\,.$

Comment: (A) In the Case here , $c(x)=0$ when Degree of $f(x)$ is 0 & 1. When Degree of $f(x)$ is 2 or more , we have a Double root , @Angelo , thus OP is right with the title. (B) EITHER we should consider $c(x)=0=0(x-a)^2$ OR that Double root should be removed !

Comment: @Angelo The "*double root*" in the title matches the condition "*$\deg f \ge 2$*", which made me suspect that's what the problem was really asking.

Comment: @SRobertJames You basically proved that $c(a)=c'(a)=0$, which holds true in all cases regardless of degrees, but that only means that $a$ is a double root of $c$ $\color{red}{\text{iff }} \deg c \ge 2$, which happens  $\color{red}{\text{iff }} \deg f \ge 2$.